# Save Problems in Eclipse. I cannot save project files in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

[Access is denied screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/do8o1.png)

Hi everyone, i have been looking for a solution to this problem all over the internet for the past three days but my efforts were futile.

**Description**:

After the creation of a project, eclipse will allow only one save or edit of the project files and any other edits or saves after are followed by that error above (see Access is denied screenshot).

**Solutions i've tried before**:

I have tried creating new workspaces, running eclipse as an administrator and moving files in a new projects.

Any help or further discussion is welcomed.
Thank you and sorry if didnt follow the posting rules, it's my first post.

Comment: You do not have access to write to that directory. Alternatively, you dont have permission to write to that .java file.

Comment: thank you for your comment, indeed all my folders and file became read only "somehow" (windows upgrade did that)
i found this solution that worked for me https://blog.switchfast.com/solved-windows-10-upgrade-changed-all-documents-to-read-only